# Terminal Serenity BDD tests skip

Tags: java, selenium, serenity-bdd

I have a problem with running tests in Terminal for Serenity BDD, more specifically. 
( mvn verify serenity:aggregate )

[Here is a SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grzSK.png)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the Surefire and failsafe plugins and now my only warning is sun.rmi.runtime.Log is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release.